# Selected row to textbox when clicked on row not firing

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview

I can click on row to selected them but when i need them to textbox it's not firing i tried to use Autopostback on textbox but it's doesn't work i think it's because of for each that not make row.cells(0) work
i write a code like this

VB.NET

```
  Protected Sub OnSelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    For Each row As GridViewRow In GridView1.Rows
        If row.RowIndex = GridView1.SelectedIndex Then
            row.BackColor = ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#E294FF")
            txtrepname.Text = row.Cells(0).Text
            row.ToolTip = String.Empty
        Else
            row.BackColor = ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#FFFFFF")
            row.ToolTip = "Click to select this row."
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Gridview

```
 <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
    DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" ShowFooter="True" Width="1280px"    OnRowDataBound = "OnRowDataBound" OnSelectedIndexChanged = "OnSelectedIndexChanged"
    onrowupdating="GridView1_RowUpdating" DataKeyNames="REP_NAME" PageSize="9999">

    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="" >        

            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkEdit" runat="server" Text="" CommandName="Edit" ToolTip="Edit"
                CommandArgument=''><img src="Images/ad_edit.png" BORDER="0" /></asp:LinkButton> 
                <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkDelete" runat="server" Text="Delete" CommandName="Delete" 
                ToolTip="Delete" OnClientClick='return confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this entry?");'
                CommandArgument='' BorderColor="#CC3300"><img src="Images/ad_delete.png" BORDER="0" /></asp:LinkButton>    
            </ItemTemplate>
            <EditItemTemplate>                                    
                <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkInsert" runat="server" Text="" ValidationGroup="editGrp" CommandName="Update" ToolTip="Save"
                CommandArgument=''><img src="Images/ad_save.png" BORDER="0" /></asp:LinkButton>
                <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkCancel" runat="server" Text="" CommandName="Cancel" ToolTip="Cancel"
                CommandArgument=''><img src="Images/ad_reload.png" BORDER="0" /></asp:LinkButton>
            </EditItemTemplate>
            <FooterTemplate>                                    
                <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkInsert" runat="server" Text=""  ValidationGroup="newGrp" CommandName="InsertNew" ToolTip="Add New Entry"
                CommandArgument=''><img src="Images/ad_add.png" BORDER="0"/></asp:LinkButton>
                <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkCancel" runat="server" Text="" CommandName="CancelNew" ToolTip="Cancel"
                CommandArgument=''><img src="Images/ad_reload.png"  BORDER="0"/></asp:LinkButton>
            </FooterTemplate>
            <HeaderStyle Width="60px" />
        </asp:TemplateField> 
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Report Name" SortExpression="REP_NAME" >
            <ItemTemplate>
                <div style="overflow:hidden; text-overflow:ellipsis; white-space:nowrap; min-width:150px; ">
                <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("REP_NAME") %>'></asp:Label>
                </div>
            </ItemTemplate>
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("REP_NAME") %>'></asp:Label>
            </EditItemTemplate>
            <FooterTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtREP_NAMENew" runat="server" CssClass="" Width="60px"   ></asp:TextBox>
                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="valREP_FILEID" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtREP_NAMENew"
                Display="Dynamic" ErrorMessage="Province is required." ForeColor="Red" SetFocusOnError="True"
                ValidationGroup="newGrp">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
            </FooterTemplate>
            <HeaderStyle Width="80px" />
        </asp:TemplateField>

    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Comment: Post your `GridView`

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.selectedindexchanged(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: it's not help my solutions is i don't need to use select button

Comment: in `OnSelectedIndexChanged` event using `GridView1.SelectedRow` you can get `GridViewRow` from there and find `row.Cells(0).Text`.

Comment: it's show Expression is of type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRow', which is not a collection type.

Comment: i solved a problem by using

txtname.text = CType(gridviewname.SelectedRow.FindControl("Label_Name"), Label).Text thanks for your help :)